# triggering click on label does not run ng-change on its radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wrote a directive that successfully selects a radio button when you're focused on its label and hit spacebar. However - even though the radio button becomes checked, it does not run `ng-change` function `action()`

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="Yes" ng-model="aModel" name="bool" id="yes" ng-change="action()">
<label space-select for="yes" name="bool">Yes</label>
```

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('spaceSelect', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){  
                    var selectEvent = function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode === 32){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            element.click();
                        } 
                        };
                    element.bind('focus', function(event){
                        console.log('adding');
                        document.addEventListener('keypress', selectEvent);
                    });
                    element.bind('blur', function(e){
                        console.log('removing');
                        document.removeEventListener('keypress', selectEvent);
                    })
                }
            }
        }]);
```

Wrapping it in a safeApply or $timeout didn't help.

Any idea what can be causing this?

EDIT: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/je8omc3r/)

Comment: You should be calling digest after `element.click()`, could you provide plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Where is the defination your "action" (the function) ?

Comment: @blackmiaool assume $scope.action() is properly defined in the controller who's template contains that element. it works everywhere else it's called. It even works when you explicitly click on the label. Just not when you trigger the .click().

Comment: @PankajParkar running digest or apply (even from the $rootScope) does not update the model and run ng-change

Comment: have you tried to console.log the element and the event when you press space? Please, let us know the result of that log if u cna

Comment: @mnemosdev thanks for the help - I figured it out while I was preparing the fiddle for all of you. I needed to trigger the .click() method on e.target - not element.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue while creating the JSFiddle for the fine people in the comments.

Turns out I needed to use `e.target.click();` instead of `element.click()`.

Not entirely sure why that updated the ng-change, but it did. I think it's because `e.target` refers directly to the DOM element while `element` referred to the angular element.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/je8omc3r/